# addEventListener to element clientWidth vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addeventlistener, vuejs3, watch

Hi I am trying to listen for a components clientWidth when a component gets resized. I want to use like

const myEl = document.querySelector('#myID')

and pass that myEl to be watched when myEl.clientWidth changes. Idk I've found a composable function that I can watch when the entire screen resizes but I'm not changing the screen size when the element size changes. Idk if that resize works or how it all works when using an element. This is screen resize one that works

```
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, ref } from "vue"
export default function () {
  let width = ref(window.innerWidth)
  const onWidthChange = () => width.value = window.innerWidth
  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  return { width }
}
```

and im trying something like

```
import { onMounted, onUnmounted, ref } from "vue"
export default function (el) {
  let elWidth = ref(null)
  function onWidthChange(){
    console.log('HERE')
    elWidth.value = el.clientWidth
  }
  onMounted(() => el.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  onUnmounted(() => el.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  return { elWidth }
}
```

and passing in myEl in component using it like

```
const myEl = ref(null)
onMounted(() => {
  myEl.value = document.querySelector("#myEl")
  const { elWidth } = useElementWidth(myEl.value)
  watch(() => elWidth.value,
    (wid) => {
       if(wid){
         console.log('widEL', wid )
       }
     },
  })
})
```

Also being composable is not necessary. If I can just get this clientWidth watched that would be great

Comment: You might want to use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

Answer (score 0):

Im not expert on resizeObsever but I think component like this is working for me. Not claiming perfect but its working for my purposes.. Feel free to improve it. And idk if works in every browser or whatever if works in chrome then good with me but didnt test everything

```
import { onUnmounted, ref } from "vue"
export default function () {
  const elWidth = ref(0)
  const theEl = ref(null)
  const useElID = ref(null)
  function mountObserver(elID){
    useElID.value = elID
    console.log('elWidtMounted', elID)
    theEl.value = document.querySelector(elID)
    ro.observe(theEl.value);
  }
  onUnmounted(() => {
    console.log('elWidtUnMounted', useElID.value)
    ro.unobserve(theEl.value)
  })
  const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    console.log('Size changed', entries);
    for (let entry of entries) {
      console.log('Size changed e', entry);
      const width = entry.contentRect.width
      elWidth.value = width
    }
  });
  return { elWidth, mountObserver }
}
```